# How to validate that a parameter is an integer number in UNIX?

Tags: validation, unix, integer

I am writing a script where the second parameter must be an integer, but I don't know how to check if a parameter is an integer or not.

```
if test $2 =~ "^[0-9]+$"
 then
  echo "\nNumero  entero"
 else
  echo "\nError: El numero $2 no es un numero entero !!!\a"
 fi
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Almost. I'm assuming a bash shell:

```
#!/bin/bash
result=$(echo "$2" | grep '^[0-9][0-9]*$')
if [ -n "$result" ]
then
    echo 'Integer!'
else
    echo "Error: '$2' is not an integer"
fi
```

Comment: D: It throws me this: grep: illegal option -- E
Usage: grep -hblcnsviw pattern file . . .

Comment: and this? grep '^[0-9][0-9]*$'

Comment: Now it works! Thanks a lot man...    Hey but could you tell me what topic  should I search to learn more about?

Comment: You should try to learn about the shell you're using. I assumed bash because it's the most common. For example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4651437/how-to-set-a-variable-equal-to-the-output-from-a-command-in-bash and, of course, the command "man grep" or any text about regular expressions